# "Couldn't connect to remote machine." error in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, process, remoting

I want to get the process in a remote system using vb.net for that i have use getProcess() method. when i am trying to execute the code it is showing an error like "Couldn't connect to remote machine" .i know there should have certain privilege to use this.but i don't know how to set the privileges and what all are it. if any one knows please help me

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information from this [blog post](http://sebastienlachance.com/post/ProcessGetProcesses-common-errors.aspx) might be helpful:

> Here is a list of common errors I had while working with the
>   System.Diagnostics.Process class. I listed all solutions that worked
>   for me.
>
> Solution 1: Open MMC (Start/Run/mmc), add the Services snap-in and
>   enter the name of the machine you are trying to connect to. This
>   should give the exact reason it’s failing.
>
> Solution 2: The inner exception could give you more information.
>
> Solution 3: You need server permission.
>
> Solution 4: Common on Windows 7 and Vista, start the Remote Registry
>   service.

Comment: Thank you fro replay i think this will help me.